# React Native - How to get key for array mapped components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I created this simple 'Base' component which dynamically creates multiple 'Box' components (via renderBoxes() method). When one of these box components is pressed, I want to know which one among all the dynamically created Box component is pressed. Is there a way for that? Are we gonna we use the 'key'?

```
import data from './dataFile.json';

class Base extends Component {

  state = {calendarData: []};

  componentWillMount() {
    //storing json data in the state
    this.setState({ calendarData: data });
  }

  onBoxPress() {

    // HOW TO ACCESS WHICH BOX COMPONENT WAS PRESSED?

  }   

  renderBoxes() {
    return this.state.calenderData.map(ride => {
      <Box
        key={ride.id}
        onPress={this.onBoxPress}>
      </Box>
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        { this.renderBoxes() }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Please provide a short reason as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `key` prop is used internally by React to optimise the virtual rendering. While it *could* be used to pass information back to the parent, it probably shouldn't. (In fact, in dev mode I think you'll get a warning if you try to access the key prop.)

Instead, you can wrap the `onPress` callback in an anonymous function that closes over the `ride` variable:

```
  <Box
    key={ride.id}
    onPress={() => this.onBoxPress(ride)}>
  </Box>
```

You can then receive the ride in the `onBoxPress` callback:

```
onBoxPress(ride) {
  // do something with the ride
}
```

*Edit:*

Using an anonymous function wrapper has the additional benefit that is binds the `this` context of the callback function correctly. If you don't use a wrapping function, you'd have to `bind` it manually:

```
  <Box onPress={this.onBoxPress.bind(this)}></Box>
```

Alternatively, to auto-bind the `this` context you can use the class property syntax instead:

```
onBoxPress = () => {
  // `this` is now bound correctly
  this.setState(...)
}
```

Comment: Great! Don't forget to mark the question as answered, so others looking for unanswered questions needing help can see this one is solved.

Comment: Ah, the `this.setState` issue is due to the `this` variable not being bound correctly. Edited the answer to include this note.

Comment: Thanks again. That helped.